# Transform XML into string JAVA

Tags: java, xml, string

i have this method:

```
public StampaModuloPrivacyResponse generaXmlALC(StampaModuloPrivacyRequest input)
        {  
        final StampaModuloPrivacyResponse stampaModuloPrivacyResponse = new StampaModuloPrivacyResponse();
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(StampaModuloPrivacyRequest.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(input, System.out);
            /*HERE*/
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stampaModuloPrivacyResponse;
    } 
}
```

I need to transform the xml returned from marshaller in a string because i have to set in the stampamoduloPrivacyResponse.setXMLString() ...how i can do? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a StringWriter:

```
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(input, out);
stampamoduloPrivacyResponse.setXMLString(out.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here :

```
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(input, System.out);
```

you use the `marshal(Object jaxbElement, java.io.OutputStream os )` method that accepts a outputstream and  you write the xml content in the standard out.
You don't want that.

`Marshaller.marshal()` is overloaded and have a version that accepts a `Writer`.

You could so use `StringWriter` as `Writer`:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(input, writer);
String xmlString = writer.toString();
```